# can't convert my string using upper and lower case functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create a function that changes the first letter of my string to upper case and the rest of the letters to lower case. I've written the following code but it doesn't change the string when I compile it. I don't know what I did wrong here. Any pointers ?!

```js
var e1;

function capFirstLetter(myString) {        
  myString = (myString.substring(0,1)).toUpperCase();    
  myString = (myString.substring(1, myString.length)).toLowerCase();      
  return myString;
  
}

e1 = prompt("Please Enter Your First Name");    
capFirstLetter(e1);    
console.log("The result is: " + e1);
```

Comment: You have to do something with the return value of `capFirstLetter`. E.g. `e1 = capFirstLetter(e1);` or `console.log("The result is: " + capFirstLetter(e1));` or `e1 = capFirstLetter(prompt("Please Enter Your First Name"));`.

Comment: You're not doing anything with the result of the function call, so the `return myString;` is currently being ignored

Comment: You are reassigning the `myString` var instead of mutating it.

Comment: If an answer has helped. Can you please consider accepting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised none of the answers are using `.charAt(0)` and `.slice(1)` for this. It's far more cleaner and requires less code to do what OP is after.

```js
var e1;

function capFirstLetter(myString) {        
  return myString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + myString.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

e1 = prompt("Please Enter Your First Name");    
e1 = capFirstLetter(e1);    
console.log("The result is: " + e1);
```

Comment: In my case, it's because I'm not familiar with Javascript and was just replying with general programming principles in mind.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple of things wrong here.
When you input a primitive variable into a function (i.e., not an object), the variable is copied rather than moved directly.  This means that the string myString inside the function is a completely different string to the one outside the function, and changes won't be reflected in your outside string.

Secondly, you are overwriting said string with the first character (capitalised), then overwriting that again with the remaining characters, which no longer exist!  The result of this is that your function returns the empty string "".

Finally, you return this empty string from the function but don't do anything with it.

Probably you are trying to do this:

```js
var e1;

function capFirstLetter(myString) {        
  first = (myString.substring(0,1)).toUpperCase();    
  rest = (myString.substring(1, myString.length)).toLowerCase();      
  return first + rest;
  
}

e1 = prompt("Please Enter Your First Name");    
e1 = capFirstLetter(e1);    
console.log("The result is: " + e1);
```

Comment: Thanks ! One question though. You said "Secondly, you are overwriting said string with the first character (capitalised), then overwriting that again with the remaining characters, which no longer exist! The result of this is that your function returns the empty string "

How's so ?! I thought the substring() and toUpperCase() functions only changed the output of console.log and didn't overwrite the initial string.

Comment: `(myString.substring(0,1)).toUpperCase();` returns a string with a single character in it.  When you write `myString = (myString.substring(0,1)).toUpperCase();` you have assigned that string to the `myString` variable, overwriting whatever it was before.

Comment: *"the variable is copied rather than moved directly."* That happens with variables that hold an object reference as well. If `myString` was holding a String *object* (instead of a string primitive value), it would have exactly the same problem. JavaScript is pass-by-value. The value of the variable itself is irrelevant (in this case).

Comment: In FireFox and Chrome at least, this works: `o = {s: "foo"}; function bar(o) {o.s = "bar"}; bar(o); console.log(o);` prints:  `Object { s: "bar" }` The _reference_ to the object is copied, but the reference still points to the same object as the outer reference (unless you reassign it).

Answer (score -1):

`capFirstLetter(el)` returns a value. You are calling the function, but not capturing that return value and instead, just logging the original response from the `propmt`.

Additionally, you are throwing away all but the first letter in your function because you immediately overwrite the input argument with just the first letter. You need a second variable to store that.

See comments inline:

```js
var e1 = prompt("Please Enter Your First Name");

function capFirstLetter(myString) {     

  // This only returns the first letter of the string.
  // So, you don't want to overwrite the input because you'll lose the rest of the word
  var newString = myString.substring(0,1).toUpperCase(); 
  
  // Now, you have to concatenate the first letter (from above) with the rest
  myString = newString + myString.substring(1, myString.length).toLowerCase();      

  return myString;
}
  
var result = capFirstLetter(e1);    // Capture the function's return value
console.log("The result is: " + result);
```

Comment: How is this different to any of the other questions that have already been downvoted?

Comment: @fuzz Those other answers weren't there when I started working on my answer. When I posted, I didn't notice them. But, I believe my answer is clearer and provides more explanation.